# Where to catch "WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state." message

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have read many related answers but I don't find what I need. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47898118/3808307) answer uses a library

I am using websockets without library, and a Redux middleware.

The websocket does not disconnect continually, only occasionally disconnections happen.

The `WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.` message is not caught by the onerror function. It is console logged on this line `socket.onmessage = onMessage(store);`

So I am trying

```
socket.onmessage = () => {
  if (socket.readyState !== 1)  {
    console.error('Please try again later.') // this is just a test to try to handle the problem, it will not be the actua implentation
    return
  }
  onMessage(store);
}
```

IT does not work, messages are never sent. I really need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to catch open and close ready states in onopen, onclose handlers.

For example:

```
socket.onclose = () => {
    console.error('Please try again later.');        
}
```